# openlayers 3, osm and custom projection display issue

Tags: openstreetmap, coordinate-system, openlayers, mapserver

I have successfully combined mapserver and openlayers-3 in a custom projection, using proj4 library. As soon as I add osm layer, I can't see the mapserver layer anymore, even if it is the last to be called.
Is it a problem of projection ? I have read that osm data can be reprojected now since OL3 3.11.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.17.1/css/ol.css"     type="text/css">
<style>
   #map {
    height: 256px;
    width: 512px;
   }
</style>
<script src="/proj4js-2.3.14/dist/proj4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.17.1/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title>OpenLayers 3</title>
```

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:2154","+proj=lcc +lat_1=49 +lat_2=44 +lat_0=46.5 +lon_0=3 +x_0=700000 +y_0=6600000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m   +no_defs");

  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
        attributionOptions: ({
            collapsible: false //ceci ne fonctionne QUE si un fond OSM est appelé !!
                })
            }).extend([
        new ol.control.ScaleLine(),
        new ol.control.MousePosition({
                coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(4),
                projection: 'EPSG:2154' //juste à l'affichage
            })
        ]),
    layers: [

      new ol.layer.Image({
        title: 'operations Inrap',
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
          url: 'http://10.3.1.51:8080/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=C:\\OSGeo4W\\apache\\htdocs\\fond_mapserver_ol3.map',
          params: {'LAYERS': 'Interregions',
                    //'CRS': 'EPSG:2154',
                    'FORMAT': 'image/png'},
          serverType: 'mapserver',
          extent: [93501.1, 6044342.00, 1248133.25, 7115784.50]
        })
      }),
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      projection: new ol.proj.Projection({
      code:'EPSG:2154',
      units: 'm'
        }),
      //extent: [93501.1, 6044342.00, 1248133.25, 7115784.50], 
      center: [681845, 6606361],
      zoom: 6
    })  
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a projection issue, but the layer order is wrong. The OSM layer is opaque, so it needs to be added first, not last. Otherwise it will cover everything rendered underneath it.